# MultiValueDictKeyError at / 'start_date'

Tags: python, json, django

Actually when i want to change calender date in django template it must run first code and if i dont it run else par but i am getting multivalue error

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        start_date = request.GET['start_date']
        end_date = request.GET['end_date']

        start = parser.parse(start_date)
        end = parser.parse(end_date)

        _start = json.dumps({"year":start.year, "month":start.month, "day":start.day})
        _end = json.dumps({"year":end.year, "month":end.month, "day":end.day})
        url="https://backend.makerobos.com/admin_apis/?key=g223p25HE23fdg2hHJBhU545HuhI&start={}&end={}".format(_start, _end)
        response=requests.get(url).json()
        return render(request,'robosapiapp/robos.html',{'data':response})
    else:
        url="https://backend.makerobos.com/admin_apis/?key=g223p25HE23fdg2hHJBhU545HuhI&start={%22year%22:2019,%22month%22:2,%22day%22:11}&end={%22year%22:2019,%22month%22:3,%22day%22:1}"
        response=requests.get(url).json()
        return render(request,'robosapiapp/robos.html',{'data':response})
```

and this is my form page

```
<form method="GET">
     <label>From:<input id="start_date" type="date" name="start_date"></label> &nbsp;
     <label>To:<input id="end_date" type="date" name="end_date"></label> &nbsp;
     <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is always a GET, even when you first load the page. You want to only run the code when the form is actually submitted; so you should change your condition to check for a submission. One way of doing this is to look for the submit button itself.

```
def homepage(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
```

Comment: But my calendar date vanish when i click on submit button